# Why did Fleur scream in the maze?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Goblet of Fire, during the Third Task, Harry hears Fleur scream while in the maze. He assumes she is out of action. Later, Krum attacks Cedric with the Cruciatus curse. After Harry stuns Krum, he and Cedric wonder if Krum attacked Fleur, too, which would explain Fleur's scream.

Later, though, when fake Moody is talking to Harry about helping Harry through the task, he says he *stunned* Fleur and *then* had Krum attack Cedric. Why would Fleur have screamed? She would have just been knocked out, there wouldn't be any scream. How is this explained?

Comment: That's called a plot hole. A very small one.

Comment: She could have screamed at something entirely different. Harry & Cedric only *think* that's Fleur being taken out, when actually maybe she's just screaming because a giant spider lunged out at her (which she successfully defeated/evaded anyway) and then some time after that Moody takes her out silently. There's no reason to believe the scream from Moody's attack.

Comment: She was scared init?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be because Fleur must have seen someone(fake Moody) in the dark of the maze going to attack her, because he is the one who stunned her. So in that fear she would have screamed.

Answer (score 4):

[This is what the wikia has to say about it.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles'_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Books/Goblet_of_Fire/Chapter_31)

> However, due to the machinations of Barty Crouch Jr.—disguised, via
>   Polyjuice Potion, as Alastor Moody— Fleur did not last long. Crouch
>   wanted Harry to reach the Triwizard Cup so that he could be
>   transported to meet with Lord Voldemort. To achieve this, he used
>   Moody's magical eye to find Fleur in the maze and stun her.

[Also this.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire)

> As he patrolled around the labyrinth hedge, he stunned Fleur Delacour
>   and used the Imperius Curse on Viktor to get rid of Cedric, but Viktor
>   Krum was stunned by Harry.

In hindsight I remember this being the canon reason in the books. I will try to find a canon quote though as I don't have the books open in front of me now.

**Other theories**

Although I think the first theory is the best as it is mostly canon.

Maybe she saw the Fake Mooody about to attack her before she got knocked out. Or maybe she saw Victor having the Imperius curse used on him.

> [Harry hears Fleur screaming, but, is unable to locate her](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles'_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Books/Goblet_of_Fire/Chapter_31)
>
> [Along the way, he hears Fleur scream.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire)

[Maybe she saw some of this.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Viktor_Krum)

> During the task, Barty Crouch Jr, posing as Alastor Moody by way of
>   the Polyjuice Potion, managed to place the Imperius Curse on Viktor as
>   part of his plot to steer Harry Potter to victory in the Tournament.
>   Under Moody's control, he caught up with Cedric and performed the
>   Cruciatus Curse on him. However, he was Stunned by Harry and left
>   unconscious. Cedric, against his better judgement, used his wand to
>   shoot red sparks into the air, allowing him to be rescued from the
>   maze.

**Or**
Was attacked by a creature that was put in the maze.

1. Spiders
2. Blast Ended Skrewts

I personally don't think she got that far as the Fake Moody probably got rid of her as fast he could. And since she came into the maze last, she was probably easy pickings. She probably tried to run and fell or something, so she screamed. Or she saw the Fake Moody holding his wand in her face and that scared her.

***Below is my old answer, but I think its total rubbish.***

Maybe she saw Victor Krum about to attack her before she got knocked out. Or maybe she saw Victor having the Imperius curse used on him.

I don't think it is ever explained in the book. As this is all I think that happens.

> [Harry hears Fleur screaming, but, is unable to locate her](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles'_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Books/Goblet_of_Fire/Chapter_31)

And from the wikia.

> [Along the way, he hears Fleur scream.](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire)

Comment: Wikia isn't canon